# When using R curl to download a Twitter page, the page downloaded is "This browser is no longer supported"

Tags: r, curl, twitter, rcurl

So, I have an script that uses curl_download to download a Twitter page, and then use read_html to get some data off of it. It used to work fine, but now, instead of downloading the proper Twitter page, it downloads this page instead:

[image: A picture of the Twitter page with a popup sating "This browser is no longer supported. Please switch to a supported browser or disable the extension which masks your browser to continue using twitter.com. You can see a list of supporter browsers in our Help Center."]

I'm not sure how Curl would have the wrong browser, or how to change it if it does, but this is a very new problem. The reason I am doing this is so the script can grab the number of followers from the .html file (and do a bunch of other irrelevant things with it), so if anyone just happens to know a significantly easier way to do that I am open, but otherwise I'm hoping someone has seen this Curl issue.

Here is my code:

`library(curl)`

`twitter_file <- "location the file is meant to be saved"`

`curl_download("https://twitter.com/SelectFulton", twitter_file, quiet = TRUE)`

Thank you!

Comment: Every browser (including `curl`) has the opportunity to advertise a `USER_AGENT`, i.e., a string that defines something about the browser's capabilities. One of `curl`'s [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/vignettes/intro.html) says that its agent looks something like `"R (3.6.1 ...)"`, it should be possibly to manually override this. One might infer that Twitter no longer wants manual scraping (at least with an R-base `curl`). Have you considered trying the [`twitteR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/index.html) package?

Comment: @r2evans I'll have to look further into possibly overriding that, thank you! My first thought was also that Twitter may be purposefully blocking curl, though I was hoping not. The reason I didn't use twitteR in the first place was because of how Twitter had made it so difficult with creating an app and all (even for publicly-accessible data), but I've looked into it further and I'm going to try again. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@r2evans was correct about changing the user agent working! This was the code I ended up using:

`withr::with_options(list(HTTPUserAgent="Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"), curl_download("https://twitter.com/SelectFulton", twitter_file, quiet = TRUE))`

and there are no longer any issues. Thanks for the help!